# Problem installing/opening package dplyr on MacBook with R Studio latest version

Tags: r, macos, dplyr, anaconda

The following message comes after I write library(dplyr) on R:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rlang/libs/rlang.so':
  dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rlang/libs/rlang.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/R/library/rlang/libs/rlang.so
  Reason: image not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

**Using macOS Mojave 10.14**

I installed dplyr on MacBook using the following command:

> install.packages("dplyr", 
>   +                  repos = "https://cran.r-project.org", 
>   +                  type = "mac.binary.el-capitan")

Comment: I had no problems installing/loading dplyr using the same command as you. It seems like an anaconda problem...

Comment: Funny, I think that this command line should not work, but instead give a parsing error (`Unexpected '='`).

Comment: @January Yes, but install.packages("dplyr", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org", type = "mac.binary.el-capitan") works... I guess the +'s were copy-n-paste problems